# Why is my nginx error log is full of "long-running connections" messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

I'm experiencing erratic timeouts to one of my ruby on rails APIs.
A half dozen times a day an automated testing tool reports timeouts. The times aren't consistent from day to day.

I've checked the nginx error logs and see them filled with the following entries

`[ N 2019-01-31 06:23:03.2654 10831/T4 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1146 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 13386, application /var/www/rule/current (production)`

are those entries normal or a sign of something wrong?

nginx/1.15.7

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS